# "snake" run error

Tags: c++, runtime-error, 2d-vector

i'm making a simple snake game in c++. it compiles, but won't run. i'm using netbeans on a mac, and i've never had a problem like this before, so i assume it's a problem with my code:

```
#include <vector>
std::vector<std::vector<int> > snake;//the snake
int main(){
    snake[0][0]=0;
}
```

i think it might be a problem with the 2d vector.

Comment: _Won't run_ is surprisingly little to go on. Do you get errors? Warnings? Is the five lines you've given the entire program?

Comment: @sarnold: Have a look in the edit history to see the entire program. I reduced it down to a minimal case.

Comment: @Mankarse: Ah! How'd I overlook that?.. must be time to do something else.

Answer (score 5):

`snake[0][0] = 0` has undefined behaviour, because you are trying to assign to an element of the vector which does not exist.

That is - `snake.size() == 0` so accessing the first element with `snake[0]` is not a valid operation.

Comment: "So what should the OP do to fix it?"

Comment: @Marlon: Probably change the design to use a `std::vector<Point>` to represent the snake.